# Can't rename postgres database that has mixed case name

Tags: postgresql

The database's name is Parkes and I want to rename it Parkes1

I have tried

```
myconn.Execute "ALTER DATABASE ""Parkes"" RENAME TO ""Parkes1"";"
```

and pretty much every variety I can think of but they all return the message,

> error near '"Parkes"'

meanwhile if I try

```
myconn.Execute "ALTER DATABASE Parkes RENAME TO Parkes1;"
```

the message says

> unable to find database parkes

I can't see what I am doing wrong, it's postresql 9.4 that I am using and I am using ADO via the postgresql odbc library from vb6 to try to do the rename.
I can rename it fine using pgadmin3 but I need to be able to do it programmatically.

Comment: Which programming language is that?  Maybe you need to escape the double quotes inside the double quotes somehow. `ALTER DATABASE "Parkes" RENAME TO "Parkes1";` will work just fine in `psql` (or any other SQL client) - and while you are at it: avoid quoted identifiers in the first place. This is just another example why they are not a good idea

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, the string in my post appears just as you wrote it when displayed in the debug window.